# Adding an option tag to existing select in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

HTML:

```
<td>
    <select name="student">
        <option value="">--Select one --</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Now to this existing element, I need to add option tags in JavaScript.

I tried this way in JS but it is not working

```
document.getElementById("student").append("<option value="1">Pooja</option>);
```

Comment: `append` is not a method of `DOM element` Use `appendChild()`..Also note, `appendChild` should have `option element` as argument

Comment: `document.getElementById("student").appendChild(new Option(text, value))`. See [*MDN: Option()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option).